# Can't install 'libqt4-dev:i386' for skype

Tags: 14.04, apt, dependencies, skype

I'm using an Ubuntu 14.04 system and I'm trying to install skype on my system. I followed the steps given in the following link to install [here](http://www.ubuntu4u.com/howtos/how-to-install-skype-43-on-ubuntu-1204-or-ubuntu-1404). I first tried installing the .deb package from their site and **Software Center** says it needs `libqt4-dev:i386` and stops download. I tried to install directly from the software center and it gives an unmet dependencies error with `skype-bin` package. I tried to install the missing packages using apt-get but that didn't work either.

How do I fix this so I can get Skype to work properly?

**Edit#1**: I tried the following code:

`sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
wget -O skype-install.deb http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-deb
sudo dpkg -i skype-install.deb`

Skpe gets installed but it shows there were some during installation.(Deosn't list the errors though). I get this message:

`Errors were encountered while processing:
 skype`

The skype logo shows up in the launcher but it doesn't run. I tried running it from terminal and got this error:

`skype: error while loading shared libraries: libXv.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: I've tried `apt-get -f install` and fixing broken packages using synaptic. Didn't work.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install libxv-dev:i386` and then check..

Comment: I get an error saying I have some unmet dependencies. I try apt-get -f install but it shows `E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.` unable to correct dependcies

Comment: Okay, I removed the broken packages using `aptitude`. I used this code -  `sudo aptitude -fy remove mono-runtime`. But I still get the same error when I try to install skype.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to install the wrong .deb file. The link above is for Debian, while you should have picked Ubuntu. I'd suggest that you purge skype, and install it from Canonical Partners instead (`sudo apt-get install skype skype-bin`).

Comment: I just keep getting this unmet dependencies issue. How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Prior to version Skype 4.3, it was available as binary file, so that users can only download the binary file from it’s official and install it manually. But, as of version 4.3, Skype is available in the **Canonical Partners** repository.

To enable the Canonical Partners repository, go to **Software & Updates** from Unity dash. Navigate to **Other Software** tab, and enable Canonical Partners repository.

Click **Close**, and **Reload** buttons to update the cache. Then, type the following command to install Skype.

```
sudo apt-get install skype
```

**Edit**

According to [http://packages.ubuntu.com/](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libqt4-webkit-dbg/download) Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Add the following line

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main
```

Save and update
Then run

```
sudo apt-get install libxss1:i386 libqtcore4:i386 libqt4-dbus:i386 libqtgui4:i386
```

Finally run

```
sudo apt-get install skype
```

Comment: Canonical Partners is selected already.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start skype from terminal like this:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXv.so.1 skype
```

Comment: Okay I tried the code above and got this error : `ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXv.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.`

`skype: error while loading shared libraries: libXv.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`